# Keep a class object alive forever

Tags: android, multithreading, object

How can make a class object alive forever after initialise it? because the library needs about 4 minutes to create its object. after that the application will works fine. but, when i close the application, the object get destroyed and again i have to initialise the same object which takes 4 minutes. it is not user friendly(runs in an async task). is there any way to keep the object alive forever (even after application destroyed etc). or please help me to reduce the initialising time to 2 or 3 seconds. please help me brothers.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: its name Ab.jar which is an AI robot library :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking is to find a way to make an object persist in memory after the application releases said memory. Your best bet is to find a way to serialize the object to some non-volatile storage (ie: the phone's storage), and then load from there upon relaunching the application. I cannot specify how to do so because I do not know what type of object this is.